# How do I combine a regex pattern lookup and a positional lookup in python re?

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm new to regular expressions so please bear with me. Suppose I have two strings:

```
string_1 = 'aAbcDeF801020J00100870'
string_2 = 'aAbF801020J00100870'
```

Using the **re** module I can match the non numeric 1st part of the strings

```
pattern = re.compile("^[aA-zZ]*")

print(pattern.match(string_1).group(0))
print(pattern.match(string_2).group(0))

>> aAbcDeF
>> aAbF
```

but how might I get the sequence of 6 numeric characters that follow the matched pattern? i.e.

```
801020
```

Trying the following:

```
pattern = re.compile("^[aA-zZ]*......")


print(pattern.match(string_1).group(0))
print(pattern.match(string_2).group(0))
```

gives me:

```
>> aAbcDeF801020
>> aAbF801020
```

which is closer, but not quite there. I'd prefer to do this in a single pattern lookup vs. tacking [-6:] onto the end of my last attempt.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`^([a-zA-Z])*([0-9]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/bB0fpi/3):

```
pattern = re.compile("^([a-zA-Z])*([0-9]+)")

print(pattern.match(string_1).groups())
print(pattern.match(string_2).groups())
```

Output:

```
('aAbcDeF', '801020')
('aAbF', '801020')
```

*Explanation*:

```
^                           // asserts position at start of the string
    (                       // start of matching group 1
        [a-zA-Z]            // matches a character present in the list
        *                   // matches between zero and unlimited times (greedy)
    )                       // end of matching group 1
    (                       // start of matching group 2
        [0-9]+              // matches any number between 1 and unlimited times
    )                       // end of matching group 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
^([aA-zZ]*)(\d{6})
```

Like so:

```
string_1 = 'aAbcDeF801020J00100870'
string_2 = 'aAbF801020J00100870'

pattern = re.compile("^([aA-zZ]*)(\d{6})")

print("Full match:", pattern.match(string_1).group(0))

print(pattern.match(string_1).group(1))
print(pattern.match(string_2).group(1))

print(pattern.match(string_1).group(2))
print(pattern.match(string_2).group(2))
```

Giving you the output:

```
Full match: aAbcDeF801020
aAbcDeF
aAbF
801020
801020
```

Where `group(1)` would contain the text to be matched and `group(2)` would contain the 6 digits.
If you'd like, you can get the text **as well as the 6-digit number** with `group(0)`

---

**[Here's a fully functioning demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Kw1bAQ/1)**

As you can see in the Match Information provided on the page, the full match found is the letters along with the 6-digit number.

**Note -** Additionally, if you would like to find **all** occurrences of this pattern, you could use `re.findall()` like so:

```
string_1 = 'aAbcDeF801020J00100870'
string_2 = 'aAbF801020J00100870'

print(re.findall('([aA-zZ]*)(\d{6})', string_1))
print(re.findall('([aA-zZ]*)(\d{6})', string_2))
```

Which results in an array of tuples like so:

```
[('aAbcDeF', '801020'), ('J', '001008')]
[('aAbF', '801020'), ('J', '001008')]
```

Comment: @ coffeehouse: Thank you for this. The regex demo site is pretty great, too.